# Phonegap Filetransfer Upload Issue with WCF OData

Tags: c#, wcf, file-upload, cordova, odata

I am trying to upload file using phonegap "FileTransfer". I am using **.NET WCF OData** for uploading the image.
The "upload" function not calling my API, and returns the below error message:

```
{"code":null,"source":null,"http_stats":null,"body":null}
```

my described code is as below:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){ 
var url = encodeURI("http://api.xyz.com/DataService/DataService.svc/UploadImage");

    var params = new Object();
    params.id= parseInt(1);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = true;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, url, function (data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)) }, function (data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)) }, options);
}
```

and my **WCF OData** code is as below:

```
[WebInvoke]
public void UploadImage(int id)
{
    // **what to write here???**
}
```

I also tried with following code but **window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI function throws an Error calling method on NPObject error**

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURI) {
var _this = this;
var encodedURL = encodeURI("http://api.xyz.com/DataService/DataService.svc/UploadImage");
try {
 this.op = new FileUploadOptions();
 this.op.fileKey = "file";
 this.op.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 this.op.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
 this.op.chunkedMode = false;
 this.op.headers = { Connection: "close" };

 this.ft = new FileTransfer();
 if (window.device != undefined && device.platform == "Android") {
     window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function (fileEntry) {
         fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
             var fileFullPath = fileObj.fullPath;
             _this.op.fileName = fileFullPath.substr(fileFullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
             _this.ft.upload(fileFullPath, encodedURL, function (data) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data)); }, function (data) { alert("Failour: " + JSON.stringify(data)); }, _this.op, true);
         });
     });
 } else {
        this.ft.upload(imageURI, encodedURL, function (data) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data)); }, function (data) { alert("Failour: " + JSON.stringify(data)); }, this.op, true);
   }
} catch (_error) {
 alert(_error);
 }
},
function (message) { },
{
 quality: 50,
 destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
});
}
```

Comment: imageURI is a navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI

Comment: I mean to say did u made use of [window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem) to get the actual file path

Comment: I tried with above code but window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI function throws an **Error calling method on NPObject error**